# Visual Studio 17.3 new features not working - is there a solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Here are some new features from version 17.3 (which is now supposed to be the stable edition, not in preview anymore) [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes):

> - Collapse #regions on file open
> - Collapse usings on file open

Both simply don't work as well as this one:

> Audio Cues in the Editor

Which is not present where they say it is. I.e. in "Preview Features" under Environment.

I'm running Visual Studio 17.3 on Windows 10 with the latest updates.

Any way to fix these problems?

(Maybe it has to do with the fact that the release notes for the stable build (see link above) still show the "pre" icon, and they even have the box titles "Important" saying it's a preview release.)

Comment: VS 17.4 just got released, and should fix the issue. I have edited [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73354758/6309) accordingly.

Comment: @VonC Thank you for taking the time to come back to let me know! Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if this is related to the following prerequisite:

> To enable audio cues, head to Tools\Options and look for "Preview Features" under Environment.

Without that, those new options might not work.

See "[Listen Up, Visual Studio has a new feature you need to hear about!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/audio-cues-in-visual-studio-2022-17-3-preview-2/)"

Aug. 2022: The option was in 17.3 preview 2, but was [reported missing in 17.3 final](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Audio-Cues-Option-Not-Available/10116630?space=8&q=audio%20cues).
This is currently being investigated.

[image: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2022/06/Preview-Features-with-Audio-Cues.png]

## Nov. 2022: this is resolved with VS 17.4.

---

The collapse options are from [PR 60743](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/60743), with the options panel being:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/754264/163326670-5d32642d-fbde-440b-9de1-5ef1ddb595a0.png]

> It's worth noting that VS remembers the outlining state for all files so if you change the checkbox you should delete the `.suo` file, or the `.vs` directory, and then check what happens when you open a file.

Comment: @ispiro I have rephrase the first sentence. And added the options for the collapse part. Do you see those options in your Visual Studio?

Comment: As I said in the question, the audio option "is not present where they say it is. I.e. in "Preview Features" under Environment." - It's not there.

Comment: As for the other ones, as I said "both simply don't work." - They are checked. They just don't work.

Comment: @ispiro You don't see it in preview features? (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/preview-features-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: @ispiro Yes, I have edited the answer to explain why they might not work.

Comment: Thanks! deleting the `vs` folder helped.

Comment: Correct. I don't see it in the preview features. Do you? (Assuming you're running version 17.3)

Comment: @ispiro Strange, it was in 17.3 preview 2: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/audio-cues-in-visual-studio-2022-17-3-preview-2/

Comment: I'm on `17.3.0` (not preview). Maybe they just removed it and forgot to update the documentation, just as they forgot to remove the message about it being preview. Oh well...

Comment: I see it on your screenshot (assuming that's what it is). But it's not present in mine. Are you running `17.3.0`?

Comment: @ispiro No, preview 2 only. 17.3 final has *not* this option indeed. I have added a link to a community discussion reporting what you see, meaning the option missing.